# Rationale beyond null for reference types

Tags: c#

I am new to the language coming from a C++ background and I have a hard time understanding the reason for allowing a reference type to be null.

Consider the following snippet

```
class Person {
  private string _name;
  public Person(string name) {_name = name;}

  void print() {
    Console.WriteLine(_name);
  }
}
```

Now there is nothing to stop a caller from doing the following

```
Person p = new Person(null);
p.print();
```

This will crash, I can safeguard this (not really) by throwing an exception if null was passed to the constructor, but that just means I crash on the first line if it is not caught (which I cannot enforce AFAIK in C#) instead of the second line.

The caller has to read the documentation (which means I cannot forget to document that the constructor might throw) to know all of this.

- What is (plausibly) the reason the language allows null reference types?
- When is this advantageous and not just a ticking timebomb? The one case I can think of is lazy initialization, wanting to allocate an object conditionally.
- How do I deal with this in code I write?

Comment: The C#8 team appears to somewhat agree:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/

Comment: First question is a holywar. You may want to read this https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare

Comment: I didn't mean to insult the language if that is how I came across, I am generally curious, "that is just how it is" is not a good rationale and I would love an in-depth understanding of this design choice.

Comment: null checks, null checks everywhere.... I agree with your frustration.

Answer (score 2):

> What is (plausibly) the reason the language allows null reference
>   types?

I may have a box on a piece of paper to write the answer to "who is the man with no eyes?". I do not have an answer to that question, so I leave the box blank. The blank box does not react to this, catch fire, and force my hand... it simply remains blank, as intended.

> When is this advantageous and not just a ticking timebomb? The one
>   case I can think of is lazy initialization, wanting to allocate an
>   object conditionally.

I have a function which can handle 'the man with no eyes', however, that man sometimes does not exist. I may detect those situations and react differently.

> How do I deal with this in code I write?

Null checks. Welcome to 2018, you c++ bare metal guys have **alot** to learn. It's stuff you already know, but that knowledge lives elsewhere, and doesn't seem relevant.. until now.

Answer (score 2):

> What is (plausibly) the reason the language allows null reference types?

Sometimes you want something *not* having a value. For example, think of node classes with a parent-child relation. It would be very unpleasant if `Parent` can never be null. Even in C++ a pointer can point to 'nothing', as in `0`.

> How do I deal with this in code I write?

This has been a problem since day 1. The C# team always expected us as developers to 'fix' this issue by have enough null checks. And that is what we have been doing.

Now, with C# 8 (still in development) there are [nullable reference types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/). When enabled, you will get a compiler error if a variable that may not be null is assigned null, or possibly null.

Answer (score 1):

If we reverse the question...

Since you come from C++, we can ask "How does C++ get away with references that cannot be null".  The simple answer is "well, it has null pointers, so it doesn't need null references".  Having two differing kinds of variables that represent references to objects (with very different rules and syntax) makes C++ *so much* simpler.

Yes, [Tony Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare) claims that null references were his "billion-dollar mistake".  However, it's hard to get a working C-family language with a simple syntax if you don't have a way to represent an unassigned reference.

Consider this simple C# code:

```
string myString;
if (condition) {
    myString = func1();
} else {
    mystring = func2();
}
UseTheString(myString);
```

The string variable must be declared in the outer scope.  If every reference variable needed to be initialized at declaration time (like C++ references), then you'd need to initialize it with something that would be thrown away a few lines down.  Yeah, you might say, that's what `string.Empty` is for.  What about types more complicated than System.String - types that are more expensive to construct?  Would they need to all have an `unassigned` value; that's getting awfully close to `null`. Hey, JavaScript has both (null and unassigned)!

C++ references are extremely handy, but they are also very constraining.  Not only must they be assigned something when they are declared, they are also immutable (the variables - not the objects to which they refer).  Once you declare and initialize a C++ reference, you can't change what it refers to.  If C# references followed this rule, the code below would be interesting to write (ignore the fact that string concatenation in a loop is almost always a bad idea):

```
string myString = string.Empty;
for (var i = 0; i < someValue; ++i) {
    myString = myString + SomeFunc(i);
}
```

Then, there are things that are naturally null to consider, like, for example, nullable stuff in relational databases.  It's no surprise that nullable value types (`Nullable<T>`) showed up in the first major post v1 release of the framework.  Lots of us remember (and some of us still cope with) the pain of the DbNull type (and value).

Yeah, coping with nulls is a pain.  It's there in most (but not all) languages.  The C# language (with a combination of reference types and value types sharing a single variable syntax) is much easier to read/understand/pickup than C++.  I find I write *a lot* fewer bugs in C# than I did as a C++ programmer (though, I was a 90s-era C++ programmer, before all the recent changes to the language).

The C# 8.0 folks think they have a solution (it's not a full solution, but it should make null-reference exceptions a lot rarer).  I'm curious what your thoughts are about how C# might have avoided Dr. Hoare's billion dollar mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This way `null` won't be used as value.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person(null);
        person.PrintName();
    }
}

class Person
{
    private string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name ?? "My name can't be null";
    }

    public void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Name);
    }
}
```